# css styling not rendering properly, possible div issue?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a horizontal menu layout in CSS. I was using the guide listed here:
http://www.devinrolsen.com/pure-css-horizontal-menu/

I've got a css file looking like this, called navigation.css:

```
.navigation{
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  background-color:lightgray;
}
.navigation ul {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.navigation ul li {
  display:inline;
  height:30px;
  float:left;
  list-style:none;
  margin-left:15px;
}
.navigation li a {
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.navigation li a:hover {
  color:black;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
.navigation li ul {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  display:none;
}
.navigation li:hover ul {
  display:block;
  width:160px;
}
.navigation li li{
  list-style:none;
  display:block;
}
```

and in my actual php page, I have this

```
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#">something</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="./hello.php">Hello</a></li>
        <li><a href="./hello2.php">hello2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Browse database</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="./test.php">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="./test2.php">Test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="./search.php">Search</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For reasons I cannot determine, their is no drop-down menu effect. Consequently, if I change navigation to an id instead of a class by replacing .navigation with #navigation, then none of the layout affects the HTML.

Comment: The dropdown seems to be working, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/WaqjY/

Comment: I cut out some of the original code from my HTML, perhaps the problem lies there..I will look back, thanks

Comment: Do you have any content below your menu that might be rendering over top your menu dropdown?

Comment: No, what's actually happening is that the submenus (test, test2, hello, hello2) are displaying on the page even without hovering my cursor over them

Comment: Very odd. Works fine in IE 7+

Comment: I have discovered that the css file is getting truncated for some reason thus cutting out the code responsible for making the layout. It is unrelated to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you're still having the problem, have you tried changing:

```
.navigation li li{
  list-style:none;
  display:block;
}
```

To:

```
.navigation li li{
  list-style:none;
  display:none;
}
.navigation li:hover li{
  display:block;
}
```